# Collection gesture class

Tags: java

I have some object that are periodically loaded in my application. To access them all quickly, sort them and more, I store them in a collection.

My problem is, since this collection doesn't belong in any of my current classes I created its own final class, only to stock it and manage it, with private constructor and only static methods and attributes.

```
public class MyObject {
    //stuff
}

public final class LisOfMyObject {
    private static ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    private LisOfMyObject {}

    private static void addObject(MyObject object) {
         //stuff
    }
    private static boolean isInList(MyObject object) {
        //stuff
    }
    // etc...
}
```

I'm uncomfortable with the full static methods and attributes. How do I call this? A static class? A static singleton?

Comment: There is no such thing as best practice. Rid yourself of that misconception immediately.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "gesture" in this question? I am not sure if this is a translation error or some jargon of which I'm ignorant.

Comment: @erickson translation error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn this class into a singleton you could change it to:

```
public final class LisOfMyObject {

    private static LisOfMyObject _instance;
    private ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    private LisOfMyObject {}

    public LisOfMyObject instance() {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new LisOfMyObject();
        return LisOfMyObject;
    }

    private void addObject(MyObject object) {
         //stuff
    }
    private boolean isInList(MyObject object) {
        //stuff
    }
    // etc...
}
```

and then access it as;

```
    LisOfMyObject.instance().addObject(obj);
```

Personally I would prefer this style of class as it is removes the need to declare everything static.

Comment: That not really a Singleton. I dont have any none static method so I never need to instanciate it. The static declaration is not needed, it is just logical for every methodes. 

I mean it is not an object that Iwant to store or refere to, that just a list of utils methodes.

Comment: @JulienMaret A singleton is just a class that is only instantiated once https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/singleton-1577166.html. You definitely don't need to have non-static methods and this isn't the only way to implement your code (Your's is fine too), this was just to show another possibilty

Comment: @AndyTurner That's a completely fair comment. You're right this isn't thread-safe. I didn't add any synchronisation as it wasn't mentioned in the question and I wanted to keep the example basic

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have my answer that a stateless Singleton. I'll preinstanciate it since i need one at every execution, and it make it thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to type less, you can use [`import static`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import) and then you can call the static methods without writing `LisOfMyObject.` in front of them:

```
import static LisOfMyObject.*;

class SomeClass {
  public void doWeirdStuff() {
    ...
    MyObject something=...
    if(!isInList(something)) {
      addObject(something);
    }
```

However using this magic can make the code harder to follow (of course not for the compiler, but for a human being).